# Using a Wordpress theme from another install on same server

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have two installs on the same server, I need install B to use a theme from install A how do i do this??

Answer (score 0):

You can [Create a Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) of sites (synonyms: **multisite**, WPMU).

BTW you should ask this on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

EDIT: the documentation specific to themes in a multisite WP is here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Multisite_Network_Administration#Themes

> All themes are installed for the entire network. If you edit the code
>   of one theme, you edit it for all sites using that theme. You can
>   install the plugin WordPress.com Custom CSS to allow each site to
>   tweak their own CSS without affecting anyone else. You can activate
>   themes for the entire network, or edit sites and activate them
>   individually.

Comment: The installs are already made, data.. i can't revert to a MU.